# How can I restore Coolbar Band Order?

Tags: vb6, toolbar

I have a Coolbar in VB6 which has has 6 Bands, each of these Bands has a Child of type Toolbar. The user can move these Bands around and set their visibility. I need to restore the settings when the software is restarted, but I am having some problems restoring the order/location (I can restore the visibility and width's with no problems).

The settings I am having problems restoring are Coolbar.Bands(Index).Position and Coolbar.Bands(Index).NewRow, as both of these properties are read-only.

I know I could save the Position and NewRow properties and then create each of the Bands at run-time instead of design-time, and then using the saved properties to determine the order in which to create the Bands.

I would prefer not to have to create the Bands at run-time but I suspect it may be the only way to restore these settings. Does anyone know of a way to restore the order/location of the Toolbars without having to create the Bands at run-time?

I can save/load the settings easily enough, so we can skip that step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly. However, the following code should give you the same effect as being able to move bands around:

```
Private Sub MoveBand(ByVal the_nFromIndex As Long, ByVal the_nToIndex As Long, ByVal the_bNewRow As Boolean)

    Dim oOldBand            As Band
    Dim oNewBand            As Band
    Dim sKey                As String

    With CoolBar.Bands
        Set oOldBand = .Item(the_nFromIndex)
        sKey = oOldBand.Key
        oOldBand.Key = vbNullString
        Set oNewBand = .Add(the_nToIndex + 1, sKey, oOldBand.Caption, oOldBand.Image, the_bNewRow, oOldBand.Child, oOldBand.Visible)
        Set oOldBand = Nothing
        .Remove the_nFromIndex
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, shame it's not possible to do it directly but this should work fine.